# scrollView.setContentOffset does not scroll the view, at all

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've been following [this](http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/04/how-to-make-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present/) and a bunch of other tutorials/blogs,etc trying to get my view to scroll when the user hits "return" and ends on a UITextField that is being covered by the keyboard but nothing is actually working.

I'm wondering what must I be doing or missing that is causing this?

Basically:

- the user wants to do something in the app: add a credit card
- show a UIView that contains all the CC fields
- 1/2 of the UITextFields are covered by the keyboard
- scroll the view when the user gets there.

Nothing is happening. The code for detecting the 'covered by keyboard' case is being hit and executed but: `[self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES]` has no effect at all.

Thoughts?

Reveal screenshot:

[image]

code: same as the tutorial in the link. Nothing new there.

Comment: can you show/post your code?

Comment: have you set the contentSize of the scrollview after adding contents?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the contentSize property?

To make a scroll view scrollable, the content must be larger than the display area(usually the bounds of the scrollview).

You can achieve this by explicitly setting the [contentSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) property which is CGSizeZero by default

In addition, setting the [contentInset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset) property to adjust the size of display area(in this case you can set bottom value equals keyboard height) when the keyboard is popped up

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

     [yourTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(yourTextField.frame.origin.x, yourTextField.frame.origin.y-keyboardHeight, yourTextField.frame.size.width, yourTextField.frame.size.height)];
   }];
}
```

and

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [yourTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(yourTextField.frame.origin.x, yourTextField.frame.origin.y+keyboardHeight, yourTextField.frame.size.width, yourTextField.frame.size.height)];
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do to avoid the textField being covered by the keyboard is to animate the textfield to the top of the screen when the user touches it to start entering something with the keyboard and animate it back when done. It is much more elegant in my opinion. Maybe that could be an alternative solution for you... I do it for the different screensizes with different numbers... you might need to adjust it of course...

So listen to the textField delegate and in

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
```

you do

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        if(result.height == 480){

        ({[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f]; CGRect frame = self.view.frame; frame.origin.y = -196; [self.view setFrame:frame]; [UIView commitAnimations];});
        }

        if(result.height == 568){

            ({[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f]; CGRect frame = self.view.frame; frame.origin.y = -196; [self.view setFrame:frame]; [UIView commitAnimations];});
        }

        if(result.height == 667){

            ({[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f]; CGRect frame = self.view.frame; frame.origin.y = -238; [self.view setFrame:frame]; [UIView commitAnimations];});
        }

        if(result.height == 736){

            ({[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f]; CGRect frame = self.view.frame; frame.origin.y = -251; [self.view setFrame:frame]; [UIView commitAnimations];});
        }
```

and in

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
```

you just animate back

```
({[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f]; CGRect frame = self.view.frame; frame.origin.y = 0; [self.view setFrame:frame]; [UIView commitAnimations];});
```